# Why this json_encode returns string instead of object?

Tags: php

I'm using `json_encode` to convert an associative array to JSON format. But When I try to print the property of **`data`** accessed through Ajax from this PHP file, it shows **undefined**. When I checked the type of data, it returns **string**.

```
$elem1= "<div class='menuitems'>
                        <div class='menu1'>".$row['name']."<span class='srno'>".$row['srno']."</span></div>
                        <div class='menu2'>".$row['email']."</div>
                        <div class='menu3'>".$row['password']."<span class='cross'>X</span></div>
                        <div class='clear'></div>
                    </div>";
$elem2=$row['category'];
$array=array(
        "elem1"=>"$elem1",
        "elem2"=>"$elem2"
    );
echo json_encode($array);
```

Why is it so? How can I access the `elem1` and `elem2` through this string?

Comment: JSON is a string format ...

Comment: Call `json_decode()` to decode it.

Comment: The whole point of JSON is to convert arrays and objects into strings, so you can send them over the network or save it in a file.

Comment: Post your AJAX code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always HTTP responses will be of **string** data type. You need to parse the JSON before you can use. There are two ways. You need to use:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    typeof data; // object
});
```

In contrast to:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    typeof data; // string
});
```

If you are using the above one, you need to use:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    typeof data; // string
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    typeof data; // object
});
```

> **Note:** I am using AJAX from jQuery. The conversion, which is very specific is in pure JavaScript.

Comment: You used $.get. Is it valid for $.ajax as well? What's the difference between $.get and $.ajax?

Comment: @VikasKumar Yes! `$.get` is a short cut for `$.ajax` using URL.

Comment: Ok you don't need to define `type` etc ?

Comment: @VikasKumar No! That's the whole point of using a shortcut. `:)`

Comment: @VikasKumar Also, have a look at the API for more information: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. There it says, it is a shorthand of AJAX function and they have also given details.

Comment: @VikasKumar OMG... Why What happened?

Comment: Weak aptitude. Not enough skills.

Comment: @VikasKumar Ah don't worry. Will get soon. There's always a next chance... `:)` Keep trying.

Comment: How to make my aptitude strong? Precisely, I take more time on solving simple things than half of my class. And that half is not much intelligent than me => My aptitude is weak.

Comment: @VikasKumar See what they expect from you. Learn the old or previous aptitudes and keep on trying. Don't keep yourself demotivated!

Comment: Hey now I'm getting this error (It works but one a special case I get error): "Unexpected end of json input" inside console.

Comment: @VikasKumar Looks like the JSON isn't formed well.

Comment: I think it was because when there weren't any data in the original array the JSON object was empty hence JSON.parse() caused error. I applied a condition for this and the problem is solved.